# How can I get user input (via a dialog window) in a Windows script?

Tags: windows, scripting, dialog

I'd like to create a simple search script that runs from the CMD prompt. It needs to asks for user input first e.g. "what to search".

How can I prompt the user for input (in cmd), or open a input dialog (in any standard scripting Windows language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the command prompt, you can use `StdIn`:

```
Wscript.StdOut.Write "Enter a number: "
strNumber = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine
```

[This article](http://www.ericphelps.com/batch/userin/index.htm) is a pretty comprehensive look at different ways of getting user input in Windows Scripting. It's a bit old, but still helpful.

Comment: Thanks both answers are helpful, the link desided to mark yours as solution! This will help me a lot in different situations too

Answer (score 2):

you can use user input dialog via `InputBox` function in vbscript

```
myString=InputBox("Enter")
WScript.Echo myString
```